# Build from Command Line is OK but not from Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle

I have just moved to Android Studio 4 and I have some weird issues with Gradle.
It was failing with the error:

```
* What went wrong:
Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
> Configuration compileClasspath of project XXXX is being resolved at configuration time.
```

I have then built from Command Line in order to be able to enable more information:

```
./gradlew clean
./gradlew build --scan
```

I have fixed all the errors and it now build successfully.

However when I come back to Android Studio and rebuild all, I still get the same error.
I don't understand why and I don't know what I could do now!

Do you have some advices?

**EDIT:**

I have just seen in Android Studio that it failes with the following error:

```
Analytics other plugin to proto: Unknown plugin type com.android.ide.gradle.model.builder.AndroidStudioToolingPlugin expected enum COM_ANDROID_IDE_GRADLE_MODEL_BUILDER_ANDROIDSTUDIOTOOLINGPLUGIN
Analytics other plugin to proto: Unknown plugin type org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.IdeaPlugin expected enum ORG_GRADLE_PLUGINS_IDE_IDEA_IDEAPLUGIN
Analytics other plugin to proto: Unknown plugin type com.android.ide.gradle.model.builder.AndroidStudioToolingPlugin expected enum COM_ANDROID_IDE_GRADLE_MODEL_BUILDER_ANDROIDSTUDIOTOOLINGPLUGIN
Analytics other plugin to proto: Unknown plugin type org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.IdeaPlugin expected enum ORG_GRADLE_PLUGINS_IDE_IDEA_IDEAPLUGIN
Analytics other plugin to proto: Unknown plugin type com.android.ide.gradle.model.builder.AndroidStudioToolingPlugin expected enum COM_ANDROID_IDE_GRADLE_MODEL_BUILDER_ANDROIDSTUDIOTOOLINGPLUGIN
Analytics other plugin to proto: Unknown plugin type org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.IdeaPlugin expected enum ORG_GRADLE_PLUGINS_IDE_IDEA_IDEAPLUGIN
Analytics other plugin to proto: Unknown plugin type com.android.ide.gradle.model.builder.AndroidStudioToolingPlugin expected enum COM_ANDROID_IDE_GRADLE_MODEL_BUILDER_ANDROIDSTUDIOTOOLINGPLUGIN
Analytics other plugin to proto: Unknown plugin type org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.IdeaPlugin expected enum ORG_GRADLE_PLUGINS_IDE_IDEA_IDEAPLUGIN
Analytics other plugin to proto: Unknown plugin type com.android.ide.gradle.model.builder.AndroidStudioToolingPlugin expected enum COM_ANDROID_IDE_GRADLE_MODEL_BUILDER_ANDROIDSTUDIOTOOLINGPLUGIN
Analytics other plugin to proto: Unknown plugin type org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.IdeaPlugin expected enum ORG_GRADLE_PLUGINS_IDE_IDEA_IDEAPLUGIN
```

Comment: What happens if you do `./gradlew clean assembleDebug` ?

Comment: I have done what you suggest. The build is in fact OK from Android Studio but it is the "Gradle Project Sync" that failes (still with the same error)

Comment: Try two things: 1. CLone the project in a new folder (if you have it in version control) and try again. 2. Download a new copy of android studio (what OS are you on?) and try with fresh settings (do not import). It's strange, not sure what can be causing this, did you change anything that you can think of?

Comment: I'm on Windows 10. I have done the step 2 with fresh settings but I still have the same problem. I cannot see anything special. I have been using this project for years without issues. There is something wrong with this project because I have other projects that don’t show this problem. For this project, I have tried to clean all the files built + the .idea and the .iml files.

Comment: Still the same problem: From Command Line, the commands "./gradlew clean" and "./gradlew build" are successful. From Android Studio, Gradle Sync fails.

Comment: Well, before going too crazy about what *could* be the problem, do you have another machine to test? or perhaps a new user on the same machine, create a new user account, install Android Studio, clone the project, and open it. If it fails, something is broken either in the project itself (checkout an older version??) or the machine has a weird problem but I'd start from there first before going too crazy.

Comment: If the project is not HUGE, you can always create a new one, and drag/drop the files (which would also help to clean them up) :) and create a new one. In fact, if you do a file >  new project -> Empty Activity -> does it RUN?

Comment: Did anyone find the solution?